# Facebook like box stream

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-like

Facebook like box is only showing posts that are within previous 30 days.

Is there a way we can set this so that it shows previous number of posts rather than based on dates?

Otherwise if you don't post anything after 30 days you get an empty stream which is bad..

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the comments box? There you can specify the number of comments the box should display. However, not sure if there is a time limit on them but sure worth giving a try: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/comments/

Comment: Thank you for this but I think I need a like box...I don't know why Facebook does not give us this option...I guess it's an attempt for them to get us to post more regularly...